# How to securely store hard-coded API credentials in Javascript

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to store my API credentials in AngularS (for mobile apps and web). I've seen huge companies pass these in JS which can be exposed on the index.html file. I wish to secure these creds without obfuscation.

Thank you

Comment: No private information should be stored on client side. That being said it is a normal practice is to share some insensitive information, such `client ids`, basic database configurations etc

Answer (score 3):

There is no secret on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Services like Parse and Firebases has Object-Level Permissions. You can create users and assign them permissions to each objects. Someone with your api key needs to be authenticated as user who has permission to the object to access it.

When you sign up with Firebase it gives you a big red warning sign asking you to change default permissive permission

https://parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-security

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using Oauth2.0 on a proprietary API framework on PHP. I've setup permissions and so forth, but I would like to be able to offer my resources through the clientid/secret to non-users on my app and then have them sign in specifically for their own resource usage. 

It's tricky, should I just use a client Id to verify the app using my API and then allow read-only to resources until someone signs in?

Comment: yeah, I think that sounds about right. check this out: https://parse.com/questions/securing-application-id-and-api-key-in-javascript

Comment: thanks dude. yeah it was a grant type that I was missing, I assumed you needed to send the client secret with your api calls in general to assume resources but i wrote a resource permissions layer based on the grant type that i needed to use to solve that problem.